# Exporting data from jqgrid to Excel in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I am developing some enhancements for a web page and I need some assistance.  I have added a button that when clicked will take the html from a jqgrid and export it to Excel.  I thought I had it all working and then I did the cross browser test and Internet Explorer does not like the following method:

```
function exportGrid()
{
    var grid = "#diamondpassConferencePreregistrantGrid";

    var mya=new Array();
    mya=$(grid).getDataIDs();  // Get All IDs

    var data=$(grid).getRowData(mya[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
    var colNames=new Array();

    var ii=0;
    for (var i in data){colNames[ii++]=i;}    // capture col names

    var html="";

    var columnNames = $(grid).jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames');

    for(i=0;i<columnNames.length-1;i++)
    {
        html = html + columnNames[i+1]+"\t";
    }

    html=html+"\n";

    for(i=0;i<mya.length;i++)
    {
        data=$(grid).getRowData(mya[i]); // get each row
        for(j=0;j<colNames.length-1;j++)
        {
            html=html+data[colNames[j+1]]+"\t"; // output each column as tab delimited
        }

        html=html+"\n";  // output each row with end of line
    }

    html=html+"\n";  // end of line at the end

    alert(html);

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
```

This all seems to work fine for me in Firefox and Chrome.  The problem is that when I test in IE, the line:

```
 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
```

opens up a new tab telling me the webpage cannot be displayed.

I got some info from the following webpage:

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/10/export-table-data-to-excel-using-jquery.html

that basically tells me that line will not work in IE, that I need to set the response header as so:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.xls");
```

My problem is that I do not know what this entails.  I tried adding this line and as I would have expected, I get "Response is undefined" or something of this nature.

I was just curious if anyone had an idea as to the best way to move forward from this point.  I know how to detect the browser and I can always use different code to accomplish my Excel export for Internet Explorer but my problem is that I do not know the correct way to do the equivalent line in IE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: You cannot use a `data:` url to "download" a file in IE - that usage is not allowed by the browser.  You will need some kind of server-side code or some type of browser add-in if you want this in IE.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you know if there is another likewise way to accomplish what I am trying to do that will be supported across all browsers?

Comment: Take a look at my webpage, explanation included about that: http://jordiburgos.com/post/2013/javascript-export-to-excel.html

Comment: @jordiburgos: Which version of Microsoft Internet Explorer will work with your Javascript export to Excel?

Comment: As I point on the page, there is no support for Internet Explorer. It could be done with the new HTML5 File API on EI 11+

Comment: Just when I thought I had it working IE has to go and throw a kink in my plans lol  I may have to completely re-write this functionality unless anyone else knows of a likewise way to export to excel from IE.  I appreciate the help.  If anyone has any other ideas please feel free to let me know as it would help out tremendously.